# Executing default query in google custom search engine V2 code

Tags: javascript, html, google-custom-search

I want to automatically execute default query in google custom search engine when the page loads.
I am using v2 code of cse.

when the page loads the default should be executed automatically showing results only.
How can we do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a q param in your url:

http://example.com/?q=some_query

More difficult is using callback after the script is loaded:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#javascript

```
var myCallback = function() {
    google.search.cse.element.render();
    google.search.cse.element.getElement('my_search_el').execute("some_query");
};
```

And in html:

```
<gcse:search gname="my_search_el"></gcse:search>
```

Comment: My CSE is rendered inside an iframe, and the search term is actually modified in the parent.  I'm wondering if there's a function I can call inside the iframe that will execute a new query without reloading the iframe.